# How to get length of a response object given here

Tags: javascript, node.js, spdy

I have a proxy server, which takes request and gives a following response object pasted here http://pastebin.com/BNwCrFi1.

I'm trying to get length of response object that comes back to the proxy response.

Apparently http.response headers like 'transfer-encoding' or 'content-length' are not working.

Any ideas appreciated
I have placed the following code 
`console.log("%s:%s".yellow + " - %s - " + "stream ID: " + "%s".yellow + " - priority: " + "%s".yellow,
      socket.connection ? socket.connection.socket.remoteAddress : socket.socket.remoteAddress,
      socket.connection ? socket.connection.socket.remotePort : socket.socket.remotePort,
      req.method, res.id || (socket._spdyState && socket._spdyState.id) || "none",
      res.priority || (socket._spdyState && socket._spdyState.priority) || "none"
    );` to function dispatcher so I can get response object make logs similar to apache log format in the following file https://github.com/igrigorik/node-spdyproxy/blob/master/lib/server.js

Thank You 
Sai

Comment: Can you post an example of the code giving the issue in your post?

Comment: @admins of stackoverflow, check on who is giving consistently negative  on these questions, if they are doing it willfully, please ban them. This is very discouraging

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank You I got the answer myself socket.socket.bytesRead :)